# Why this animation using anime.js is smoother than regular CSS transition with styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components, anime.js

I've followed two aprroaches to animate a Carousel component that I'm building. I'm using React with React hooks.

**OPTION #1: with anime.js**

- I change the `selected` **state** and a `useEffect()` hook calls the animation `animateScroll()` on my component.
- The animation is done with `anime.js` as per the code below.
- What happens: some Javascript runs on background and updates an inline style `style="transform: translateX(-200%);"` according to the selected easing property.

```
function animateScroll() {
    anime({
      targets: sliderRef.current,
      translateX: selected * -100 + '%',
      easing: 'cubicBezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1)',
      duration: 1000
    });
  }
```

[image]

**OPTION #2: regular CSS transitions with styled components**

- I change the `selected` **state** and that changes a `position` **prop** of my styled-component `S.Slider_DIV` which should slide with translateX.
- Styled component then updates the `translateX` property and updates the CSS class of my `S.Slider_DIV` component with the new value for the `translateX` property.

```
<S.Slider_DIV ref={sliderRef} position={selected}>
  {imageItems}
</S.Slider_DIV>
```

```
S.Slider_DIV = styled.div`
  transform: ${props => 'translateX( '+ props.position * -100 +'%)'};
  transition: transform 1.0s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
`;
```

[image]

**THE ISSUE**

- Note that both easing functions are the same.
- On Desktop browser I can't really tell the difference between the two approaches.
- But on my phone (Galaxy A5 2017), the Option #1 with anime.js is much smoother.
- Option #2 "stutters" a little bit specially during the transition phase where the increments are smaller, like in the final part of an 'easeOutExpo', for example.

**QUESTION**

Why is that? In this simple transition example, shouldn't the regular browser CSS transition be at least as smooth and efficient than one with a JS updating the inline style?

I'll try to make an example on CodeSandBox to reproduce the difference between the two.

**EDIT:** Here's the CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tx464

Open on your mobile phone and maybe you'll see the difference. Click several times in different click frequencies.

You'll see animeJS completely smooth and the regular one with Styled-components and CSS transitions is stuttering and changing speed.

I don't even know why the one with styled-components and regular transition changes speed when toggled during an ongoing animation.

The GIF below was made on Desktop. You can see the change in speed but you can't see the stuttering effect. Also both look ugly because the GIF sample rate is too low. But test for yourself and you see the animeJS is completely smooth and you'll the issues on the other one.

Both animations have the same duration and same cubicBezier timing.

[image]

Comment: there does seem to be a short circuit there. you can cause the same bug on the mdn page for transitions by quickly moving in and out of the hover target:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: i think the reason that anime.js is smoother is that it's pretty strict about the parameters of the animation. no matter what it's going to take 2s to get to its end goal. the native transitions seem to be addressing some other use case where you're trying to quickly undo an animation you didn't mean to trigger?

Comment: @worc Yeah.. maybe this is it. It's pretty strange. I've always thought that browser would be more efficient.

Comment: it probably is more efficient if you're talking about rendering and painting to the DOM, but the implementation here is definitely a pain with this quick reset as some kind of undocumented "feature"